# Running a camera script on startup - Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: boot, raspicam, python-3, systemd-startup

I'm creating a time-lapse camera to attach to a pair of glasses.

I tried out my script (python 3) and it works, but I need to get my script to work upon startup up since it will powered by a powerbank and I can't manually start the script because of that. (filename is "GlassCam.py" in the folder named "GlassCam")

This is what I've tried in the command line:

```
sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

then in the menu

```
sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/GlassCam/GlassCam.py
```

(control+x and then y to save)

yet it won't start when I reboot it or shut it down and plug it back in

Comment: look through the 10 posts just before your post ... one of them may have what you need

Comment: put your script in `rc.local` file in `/etc`. Before the `exit` keyword, write `python3 /path/to/script/GlassCam.py`

Comment: *rc.local* from old style *SysVInit* is only emulated by *systemd* and becomes more and more deprecated. There are some feedback here on this site that it no longer work as expected. You should really use a *systemd* unit to start programs.

Answer (score 1):

For starting programs on boot you should make a *systemd* unit. I do not have enough information of detailed dependencies from your python script but as template for your needs I suggest to start with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit glasscam.service
```

In the editor insert these statements, save it and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=startup GlassCam
After=graphical.target
Wants=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/GlassCam/GlassCam.py

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Check with `systemctl cat glasscam.service` and `systemctl status glasscam.service`. Enable the new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable glasscam.service
```

Reboot.